# maximum ZXING version scanned on Android

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

What is the maximum version number of a QR code that can be scanned using Android ZXING? It seems that with my 8 MP camera, I am able to scan only upto version 20 printed as a one inch square. Is there any way to improve this?

Answer (score 2):

Up to version 40 is theoretically possible. In practice it is limited by the quality of the camera and focus. Above version 20 is pretty iffy even for a good camera. Your picture resolution is irrelevant since it uses preview mode.

Comment: does that mean that if I were to take a picture and then call ZXING core to decode QR, it might be able to decode a higher version?

Comment: Maybe, but it will probably make little difference. If the distortion due to blur is already 3-4 modules wide, it won't matter if the pixels are big or small -- the resolution won't help. But for a clear shot it might make some difference in the margin. Experiment and find out.

Comment: fyi - I can't get a version 10 code recognized with zxing on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.0, and also almost never on Galaxy S III (I was lucky and got it once). Another closed source app "QR Droid" recognizes it pretty fast though, same lighting in the room etc.

Comment: Example QR code (version 10): http://tinyurl.com/bqqctk3 which I can't get recognized with zxing.

Comment: The QR code is invalid, but it's an interesting story. I will answer on the mailing list (best to ask separate questions, not tack on one here) https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/zxing/ACm7vuCKwgw

Comment: fyi [this Version 40 QR code from Wikipedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Qr-code-ver-40.png) can be scanned directly from the monitor with Zxing on a Nexus 4 - it's a bit iffy in general, as you say, but seems to work better if you start with the phone at about 20cm out and then slowly move it forward.